# can't get the value of this input

Tags: javascript, function, dom, event-handling

I am trying to get the value of my input but it's saying mouse event. If I just call this function instead of eventListener , it's say undefined.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let pra = document.getElementById('inp1').value;
let cont = document.getElementById('container')


function execute(pra) {

    let newElemet = document.createElement('p');
    newElemet.innerHTML = pra;
    cont.appendChild(newElemet)

}
btn.addEventListener('click', execute)
```

```html
<div id="container">
      <input id="inp1" type="text">
      <button id="btn">Add</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: `function execute(pra) {` This `pra` is not the global `pra` variable. Remove `pra` altogether and change to `newElemet.innerHTML =
 document.getElementById('inp1').value;`

Comment: Yes, I have done it and it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems.

1. The `pra` argument of the event handler represents the event (a mouse event as you say) and overshadows the `pra` global variable. You can remove the argument to get rid of the overshadowing.
2. The global `pra` variable contains the value that was there (empty) when the script is loaded. You need to make the `pra` representing the input element.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let pra = document.getElementById('inp1');
let cont = document.getElementById('container')


function execute() {

    let newElemet = document.createElement('p');
    newElemet.innerHTML = pra.value;
    cont.appendChild(newElemet)

}
btn.addEventListener('click', execute)
```

```html
<div id="container">
      <input id="inp1" type="text">
      <button id="btn">Add</button>
    </div>
```